# Containing overlay text to image for mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress

I’m trying to make the text contain to the image. I have it working perfectly for desktop and tablet, but I’m having a hard time with mobile. I have made it slightly better than it was but can’t think of what I’m overlooking.

```
  /* Container holding the image and the text */
   .container {
   position: relative;
   }

  /* Bottom right text */
  .text-block {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
    padding: 0px 40px 0;
    opacity: 0.;
    }
```

Heres an image of how it looks :
[image]

Tablet : [image]

Desktop  : [image]

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="uploads/2018/09/App-Design.jpg" alt="App Design">
  <div class="text-block">
    <h6>App Design and Development </h6>
       <p>We design and develop iPhone and Android apps for startups  and   enterprises that are fully compatible with your daily operational activities.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you also show the desktop looks?

Comment: Tablet and desktop mode https://ibb.co/kLtbpz
https://ibb.co/gUA0Ge

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you're wanting to make the text for each section sit inside their respective images, and not let any text sit outside its image?

If so, use `overflow: hidden;` to hide all content that doesn't fit inside the image.

If I've misunderstood your problem, my apologies and would you be able to explain further?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to be able to read all of the content inside those boxes this cuts of the titles etc

Comment: Are you wanting the images to stay the same size that they are now? And are you happy if the size of the text changes? Not sure how good it'll look if it's all squeezed together.

Comment: im fine if the text size changes i just need all the info to be visible inside the image box as its describing what services are being offered

Comment: In that case, I would just make the font-size smaller (because it's going to look huge on a smaller device like that anyway), and reduce the 'right' value to 20 or something similar.

Comment: Don't think that's gonna work i reduced it down to 5 to get it to contained to the box and is pretty much unreadable

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set height of each container in mobile size,
for example,

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  .container {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    /* or */
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

Comment: if that doesn't work try to set `.text-block` position became `position: relative` then add `height: auto` @SteveAdams

Comment: Do you mean like

        /* Bottom right text */
         .text-block {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
           bottom: 0;
           right: 0;
  left: 0;
       color: white;
  padding: 0px 40px 0;
   opacity: 0.;
          }

Wont paste the code correctly but that drops the writing below the box

Answer (score 0):

```
 This is where im at now i feel closer but its not quite inside the box the title are still overlapping a little [Mobile view][1] https://ibb.co/dMfXez 

 /* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
 position:  relative;
}

/* Bottom right text */
.text-block {
    Color: white;
    padding:   5px 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50;
opacity: 0.;
 }
```

Comment: do you use background image? if yes maybe you can set it `background-size: cover`
i think you need to make make a Snippet or JsFiddle to mimic your issue, so we can help to figure out

Comment: I added the main HTML code to the post if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Is there away i can just make it so the description dissapears on mobile view and the title just stays there? but then the description is there on PC and Tablet mode?

Comment: sure you can. use `css media query`,  let's define the device screen sizes. usually i use 1024px for tablet landscape and 768px for tablet portrait. so add this to your style, for exanple : @media (max-width:1024px) { .text-block p{ display: block;}} and in mobile is various. for example @media (max-width: 480px) { .text-block p{ display: none;}} . don't forget to upvote my answer if it helps ^^